# android: set margin on PopupWindow by code

Tags: android

I want to set left and right margins on popupwindow. I try setting layout params on `layout` , and then set margin , but not work.

Can anyone give me code for setting margin on popupwindow

Here is code

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) QuestionsActiviy.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));


        ratePw = new PopupWindow(layout);
        ratePw.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        ratePw.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ratePw.setFocusable(true);

        ratePw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

as your layout is top on window, and you are doing this dynamically, by using width and height of screen, so to set margin 10 on sll side you can use:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) QuestionsActiviy.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));


ratePw = new PopupWindow(layout);
ratePw.setWidth(width-20);
ratePw.setHeight(height-20);
ratePw.setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: it just reduce width from one side

Answer (score 0):

My only solution was to add in custom_popup.xml layout 2 transparent relativeLayouts with width and height - 20dp(or else). Just set them to right and top of main layout.

[Bluepriont](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnzAc.png)
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Kz6.png)

Also you can use  popup.showAsDropDown(anchorVIew, 480, -100) and allocate position manually instead of showAtLocation()

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing this issue. and after spending about 2 hours I have done it on this way.

```
private void setPopUpWindow(View v) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_menu_overflow, null);
    int width = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    int height = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    boolean focusable = true;
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(view, width, height, focusable);
    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(v, 0, -customToolbar.getHeight());
}
```

And in layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/_6sdp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
    android:background="@drawable/popup_menu_rounded_bg">
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late, but the below code worked for me

```
popupWindow.apply {
            activity?.let {
                val xOffSet = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                    -20dp,                     it.resources.displayMetrics
                ).roundToInt()
                val yOffSet = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                    -10dp,
            it.resources.displayMetrics
                ).roundToInt()
                contentView = allRewardsOptionsMenuBinding.root
                showAsDropDown(anchorView, xOffSet, yOffSet)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
LayoutParams parm1=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
parm1.setMargins(20, 20, 0, 0);
layout.setLayoutParams(parm1);
//ratePw.addView(layout,parm1);  // removed it
ratePw.setContentView(layout);
```

Actually,the format of layoutParams.setMargins(left,top,right,bottom);

Comment: Try this: `ratePw.update(int Left_Margin, int Top_Margin, int Width,int Height);` adjust the width so that it will work

Comment: We cannot give margins to layout params in popupwindow. This aint work. I tried the above solution from jeet and its working like a charm (with few adjustments though).